# Align text in enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

From the code below, I wanted to be able to align the text in the enumerate environment like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Pre-Emphasis - increase amplitude of higher modulating frequencies.
\item De-Emphasis - attenuate those frequencies by the amount that were boosted by the pre-emphasis.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to align *all* second lines of the enumerate environment at the same point?

Comment: @Bernard, Hello.  Yes, I would like to align all second lines of the enumerate environment.  Thanks.

Comment: Consider the beginning of your two items do not have the same length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be better served with a `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{ }l@{ -- }X@{}}
1. &  Pre-Emphasis & increase amplitude of higher modulating frequencies\\[1ex]
2. &  De-Emphasis  & attenuate those frequencies by the amount 
                     that were boosted by the pre-emphasis
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```